# how to compare today to another date with where

Tags: php, laravel

I need to compare today to the date twenty business days after from created_at. I have afterTwentyBusinessDays function. Is it possiple to use it with where in laravel?

```php
->where(afterTwentyBusinessDays($created_at), today())
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What's not working with the current code?

Answer (score 0):

**You have to get a date that was twenty days ago and then set in where condition**

```
->whereDate('created_at', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-20 days')));
```

Comment: I think what would be more applicable would be to use `strtotime` on the result of the `afterTwentyBusinessDays` function since 20 days in the past is not the same as business days.

Comment: but it's not 20 days after, it's 20 business days after so it could be 28 days after if we count weekends and I want it works even I change the number of business days

Answer (score 0):

I presume afterTwentyBusinessDays($created_at) return carbon date time object.

Try `$query->whereDate('created_at', '>', afterTwentyBusinessDays($created_at))`

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to use carbon

```php
now()->diffInDays('2023-1-23 07:06:31')     // 19
```

`now()` will give you carbon instance alongwith UTC date and time. You can compare any dates, years, months, months, weeks even seconds.

Explore `Carbon` docs or visit detailed **Carbon** methods and their uses

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon

Why you are not using **Eloquent Model**'s own predefined methods to compare date and times like `whereDate()`, `whereDay()`, `whereMonth()` or `wheryear()` there are many.

Also you can play with these days, remember to parse in your timezone and format

```php
User::whereDay('created_at', '>', '2023-1-23 07:06:31')->get();
```